# Is time hyphenated when you spell it out? For example: "It's two-thirty."

Tags: time, hyphens

My book says:

- It's two-thirty.
- It's six-forty.
- It's five-oh-four.

But I found online:

- It's two thirty.
- It's six forty.
- It's five oh four.

I don't think people would spell the time like that on common situations but if I were to spell it out, do I hyphenate it or not?

Comment: Such matters are a question of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_style_guides) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Choster says, this is about *style* rather than grammar.  Some *[style guides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_style_guides)* may tell you to use the hyphen, while others will not.  However, all of the guides I checked recommend using numbers for times, such as *2:30* instead of *two-thirty*.

So, in answer to your question, either is fine.  If this is for your own personal writing, do whichever feels best to you.

[Edit] As Sydney says, hyphenated is probably more common. I personally prefer to hyphenate -- but I won't say the alternate is *incorrect*.

Comment: Google Ngram Viewer shows that two-thirty is used more often that two thirty, and the same for all other times from 1:30 to 12:30.